# Need to broadcast message (one-to-many) using Anypoint platform MQ with proper sequence (first-in-first-out)

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-platform

**Our requirement:** SAP will publish messages for N number of subscribers and those subscribers will fetch the published messages at their individual time interval.

**We designed the solution as this:** Created N number standard queues under an exchange. Broadcasting every message from SAP to all these N number of queues. Published API for each subscriber to fetch messages from their individual queues. For any subscribe to add the queue is getting generated with a registration API and the name of the queues are having a pattern with subscriber name.
Till this it is OK. But, we see that the messages coming from SAP has dependency to maintain sequence but standard queue can not maintain sequence. If we switch to FIFO queue we can not broadcast SAP message to all the queues together as we doing it through exchange.

My question is how we can still be able to produce SAP message to all the queues so that each subscriber can read from their individual space as well as we can maintain message sequence with first-in-first-out?

Comment: What is Anypoint queue? Anypoint MQ https://docs.mulesoft.com/mq/?

Comment: @aled yes. I meant Anypoint MQ. I have edited the title for better understanding. Here we have to use MQ because, we want subscribers to come and fetch the messages from queue than we send them to the subscriber with point-to-point call. At the same time we want to publish the same messages to all N queues so that subscriber can take them using individual pipelines and finally we need to guarantee that subscriber receives the message in the same order SAP has sent them.